# Adding objects to array in C++

Tags: c++

in header.h:

before class: class Treadmill;

private: `Treadmill* treadmillList;`

public: bool addTreadmill(Treadmill *Obj);

in header.cpp:

```
Constructor: treadmillList = new Treadmill[LISTSIZE];

bool Trainee::addTreadmill(Treadmill *Obj) {
    treadmillList[numOfTreadmills++]=Obj;
}
```

Result of compiling:

```
treadmill.cpp: In member function ‘bool Trainee::addTreadmill(Treadmill*)’:
treadmill.cpp:39:34: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘Treadmill’ and ‘Treadmill*’)
  treadmillList[numOfTreadmills++]=Obj;
                                  ^
treadmill.cpp:39:34: note: candidate is:
In file included from treadmill.cpp:3:0:
treadmill.h:3:7: note: Treadmill& Treadmill::operator=(const Treadmill&)
 class Treadmill {
       ^
treadmill.h:3:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Treadmill*’ to ‘const Treadmill&’
```

Comment: `treadmillList[numOfTreadmills++]` is an object `Treadmill`, and `Obj` is a `Treadmill*` (a pointer to `Treadmill`), so you cannot make that assignment.

Comment: What about Obj.id? it give error like maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?

Comment: Pointers are accessed with `->` instead of `.`. C++ is different from Java.

Comment: Right now what you have is a dynamic array of `Treadmill` objects. From the function `addTreadmill` it seems you want to create array to hold pointers to `Treadmill`. You should modify it like `Treadmill** treadmillList; treadmillList = new Treadmill*[LISTSIZE]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From just looking at the code you posted I think your trying to store Treadmill pointers, or addresses to Treadmill objects in an array of type Treadmill. If you want to store pointers to type Treadmill in an array try:

```
Treadmill** treadmillList;
Constructor: treadmillList = new Treadmill*[LISTSIZE];
```

This is just based on what I observed though you didnt state what you were aiming for and what your problem was exactly.

Answer (score 0):

please try this code

```
bool Trainee::addTreadmill(Treadmill *Obj) {
    treadmillList[numOfTreadmills++] = *Obj;
}
```